# search / replace in notepad++ character limit

Tags: regex, notepad++, replace

I have an xml file that needs to have a 60 character limit on certain  fields.

Example

```
<Description>This is a long description that is really over 60 characters long and needs to be shortened</Description>
```

I need to trim every occurrence so it only has 60 characters so the output for the above would be.

```
<Description>This is a long description that is really over 60 characters</Description>
```

Using notepad++ how would I do a search and replace using Regex?

I have multiple files that I need to run this against each file approximately has 2000 lines and has around 10-15 occurrences of this  field.

Not all fields have more than 60 characters just some of them.

Example block of data

```
        <Product>
        <SuppliersProductCode>PF01215</SuppliersProductCode>
        <BuyersProductCode></BuyersProductCode>
        <GTIN>0</GTIN>
        <Description>This is a long description that is really over 60 characters long and needs to be shortened</Description>
        <Properties>
            <Quantity UOMCode="EA">
                <Packsize>1</Packsize>
                <Amount>1</Amount>
            </Quantity>
        </Properties>
    </Product>
```

Thanks

Comment: Quite new to using regex so not tried much managed to get the find (<Description>)(.*)(</Description>) bit right but can't figure out the replace.

Answer (score 1):

I think the regular expression, `<Description>([^<]{0,60})[^<]*</Description>`, matches what you want assuming that the description does never contain "<". Mind that the newline character is also counted. If you want to avoid this, use `<Description>\R?([^<]{0,60})[^<]*</Description>`.

In the "replace" box you enter `<Description>\1</Description>`. `\1` references the content that is matched by the expression between the first pair of brackets. It is called a backreference. [More info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)

Comment: Edited original question to be a bit more clear this removes the <Description> tags, but I need to keep them but just edit the text in between to have just 60 characters. Thanks

Comment: I hope this is better. Let me know.

Comment: not finding any matches not every description is longer than 60 characters just some of them.

Comment: Strange, I tested it in notepad++ on your sample data and it works here. Even for descriptions shorter than 60 characters. Did you select the "regex" search mode in notepad++?